# how to make a moving label with slider thumb

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

I want to make a ranger slider bar like this which shows the current value of the slider but I don't know how can I get this... please help me

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_slider

Comment: Hi please add some more Information. It is not clear how you want to archive your goal. Do you want to use a framework? Which language are you going to use Js, ES6, Typescript ...

Comment: i don't want framework i just want some javascript code thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$("#slider").slider({
    ...
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var delay = function() {
            var handleIndex = $(ui.handle).data('index.uiSliderHandle');
            var label = handleIndex == 0 ? '#min' : '#max';
            $(label).html('$' + ui.value).position({
                my: 'center top',
                at: 'center bottom',
                of: ui.handle,
                offset: "0, 10"
            });
        };

        // wait for the ui.handle to set its position
        setTimeout(delay, 5);
    }
});
```

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RSkpH/2190/

Comment: your answer is helpful for me thanks

Comment: Most welcome. always ready to answer any query. If you more tricks required then check my personal blog http://www.99techguru.com